# Bug? Webrat doesn't find field if label contains more than input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, webrat

Trying to fill in a text input in *cucumber* using *webrat* with

```
When I fill in "Last name" with "Doe"
```

given this HTML

```
<label>
    <span>Last name</span>
    <input class="title" id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" size="30" type="text" />
    <small>Some hint text here</small>
</label>
```

will throw an `Webrat::NotFoundError` error for the input element.

If I remove the `< small >` tag, the field is found just fine.

**Is this a bug? Is there a workaround existing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not so pretty HTML. It should be this:

```
<p>
  <label for='user_last_name'>Last Name</label>
  <input id='user_last_name' [ other stuff]>
  <small>Some hint text here</small>
</p>
```

Or in ActionView terms:

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :last_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  <small>Some hint text here</small>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And yes, I guess it's debatable if it's pretty. It is valid, though (and does make good sense at least in my head ;) ) and should therefore not throw Webrat off, or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: While it may be valid it's still not going to be what Webrat's after. Don't go against the flow and you won't have these problems :(

Comment: I understand what you mean and since it solves my problem and I can see how Webrat might choke on my extravagant mark–up, I'll accept this answer. Thanks again.